Обучение расшифровке captcha
Я создал код для расшифровки капчи на примере этой картинки:

Разделил каждую букву и цифру на единицы, создал генератор таких капч,  создал больше 30 тысяч изображений в разных вариациях. Начал обучать нейронку для распознавания каждого символа, на что начал получать ошибку по изображениям. Дальше и остановился потому, что перестал понимать, как реализовать обучение и вывод готового результата в текст
Использовал библиотеку keras

Деление на буквы и цифры по 1

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array import numpy as np

def recognize_captcha(model_path, image_path):
    model = load_model(model_path)
    img = load_img(image_path, target_size=(150, 150))
    img_array = img_to_array(img)
    img_array = np.expand_dims(img_array, axis=0) / 255.0

    predictions = model.predict(img_array)
    predicted_class = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)[0]  # Для демонстрации, используем индекс класса как строку

    class_labels = {i: f'char_{i}' for i in range(36)}  # Подставьте правильные метки классов
    predicted_label = class_labels.get(predicted_class, 'Unknown')

    return predicted_label

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model_path = 'captcha_model.h5'
    test_image_path = '4RCCCK.png'
    result = recognize_captcha(model_path, test_image_path)
    print(f'Recognized captcha: {result}')


сама генерация изображений

from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha
import random
import os

def generate_captchas(output_dir, num_samples):
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.makedirs(output_dir)

    image = ImageCaptcha(width=160, height=60)
    characters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789'

    for i in range(num_samples):
        code = ''.join([random.choice(characters) for _ in range(6)])  # Генерация кода капчи
        image_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{code}.png')
        image.generate_image(code).save(image_file)
        print(f'Generated {image_file}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    output_dir = 'captcha_images'
    num_samples = 1000
    generate_captchas(output_dir, num_samples)


обучалка

⁡⁡import os
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

def build_model():
    model = Sequential([
        Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(150, 150, 3)),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
        Flatten(),
        Dense(128, activation='relu'),
        Dense(36, activation='softmax')  # 36 классов для символов и дефисов
    ])
    model.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

def train_model(model):
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
    train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(
        'preprocessed_images/parts',
        target_size=(150, 150),
        batch_size=32,
        class_mode='categorical'
    )

    # Выводим информацию для отладки
    print(f'Found {train_generator.samples} samples belonging to {train_generator.num_classes} classes.')

    if train_generator.samples == 0:
        raise ValueError("No images found in the specified directory.")

    model.fit(train_generator, epochs=10)
    model.save('captcha_model.h5')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = build_model()
    train_model(model)


О, прикольная задача, я и сам как-то хотел таким заняться и именно такой методикой решения этой задачи. Будет время - гляну что тут как.

Что-то я не вижу у вас в коде ни сегментации капчи на отдельные буквы, что само по себе сложная задача, учитывая, что буквы накладываются друг на друга, поворачиваются, сдвигаются. Ни генерации разных аугументаций при обучении (сдвигов, поворотов и прочих трансформаций). У вас какой-то простейший случай в коде обрабатывается видимо. Поэтому не очень понятно, в чём у вас вопрос. У вас код ошибку какую-то выдаёт или у вас код работает, но неправильно распознаёт капчу? Доформулируйте нормально вопрос.

код просто не может обучиться выдает ошибку по изображениям,мне бы не помешали примеры для того что бы грамотно его обучить

В смысле - неправильно предсказывает класс картинки? Сформулируйте как-то более чётко. А сегментация (разделение капчи на отдельные буквы) у вас вообще работает? Мне почему-то кажется, что вы задачу в корне как-то не так решаете. Кстати, имейте в виду, что она скорее всего и не решаемая. Все известные мне сервисы решения капч просто используют дешёвую человеческую рабочую силу для разгадывания капч. В капче самое сложное даже не классифицировать отдельную букву (это как-раз решаемо), а разделить на буквы такой текст с наползанием букв друг на друга.

А если вдруг вы пытаетесь распознать прямо сочетания букв (по 4 штуки или сколько их тут), то это вообще бессмысленно, мне кажется. И сочетаний таких очень много и трансформированы буквы для капчи могут быть множеством способов. Просто не получится подготовить достаточно большую базу картинок для обучения такой нейросети, мне кажется.

Получилось добиться первых результатов, тесты показали успех на 73 процента, сейчас я обучаю на точечное распознание букв с теми , что наползают друг на друга

Очень неплохо! Продолжайте )
